# Adding debug file to makefile build?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile for a project that I want to be used for debug and release builds. For the debug build I have to include an extra cpp file that holds all the unit tests. I have added a debug option to the makefile and everything seems to work except for one line.

My makefile is pretty long, but the offending line is in this block:

```
debug: CXXFLAGS+=-DDEBUG_TEST
debug: CXXFLAGS+=-DTEST_DIRECTORY='"$(subst /makefile,,$(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))/tests"'
debug: SRCS+=src/test.cpp
debug: flex bison $(SRCS) $(EXE)
```

The first two lines that add to CXXFLAGS are parsed successfully, as well as the last line which does the compilation. However, it seems that no matter what I do SRCS never gets the test file appended to it. I have even printed the contents before and after and it shows no change. What am I doing wrong?

I am using GNU Make 3.81 on windows.

Edit: I've decided to add the entire makefile to help answering.

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11 -U__STRICT_ANSI__
FLEX=win_flex.exe
BISON=win_bison.exe
FLEXBISONSRCS=src/parser.cpp src/tokens.cpp src/math_parser.cpp src/math_tokens.cpp
SRCS=$(FLEXBISONSRCS) src/main.cpp src/assembler.cpp src/instruction.cpp src/util.cpp
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
EXE=bin/yasa

debug: CXXFLAGS+=-DDEBUG_TEST
debug: CXXFLAGS+=-DTEST_DIRECTORY='"$(subst /makefile,,$(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))/tests"'
debug: SRCS+=src/test.cpp

all debug: flex bison $(SRCS) $(EXE)
    @echo ' $$^: $^'
    @echo ' $$(SRCS): $(SRCS)'

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

flex:
    $(FLEX) -o src/tokens.cpp src/65c816.l
    $(FLEX) -o src/math_tokens.cpp src/math.l

bison:
    $(BISON) -d -o src/parser.cpp src/65c816.y
    $(BISON) -d -o src/math_parser.cpp src/math.y

rebuild: clean all

clean:
    rm src/*.o
```

Comment: How are you testing this? That assignment is only in effect for that target and any targets that are pre-reqs of that target. (More specifically it is *not* in effect for the prerequisites of the target itself as you are trying there. So use an intermediate phony `debug` target instead of having `debug` have the build recipe (or live with the fact that changes to that test file won't trigger a make rebuild of the `debug` binary).

Comment: If by testing you mean invoking, then I use regular "make" when doing a release build, "make debug" when doing a debug build, and "make clean" or "make rebuild" when I switch from one to the other. If that's not what you meant then please clarify.

Comment: I meant how are you testing that the assignment isn't doing anything. It is absolutely changing the value of `SRCS` but the scope of that change is limited. See https://gist.github.com/deryni/897ff4584abc34fa8851 .

Comment: Oh, I see now. I am using `$(info $$SRCS is [${SRCS}])` to print out the value. The output doesn't change after the assignment and test.cpp never gets compiled even on a clean build.

Comment: Right, a toplevel `$(info)` call won't see it. The assignment is scoped such that that can't function. What is the body of the `debug` target? It must be doing the compilation itself (as you have the `.c` files and not object files listed as prerequisites). I'm assuming it probably uses `$^` in the recipe? Using `$(SRCS)` here would "fix" the problem but ultimately the simpler solution is to make the assignment global based on target being built and not target-specific. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of [target-specific variable assignments](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) is limited to the recipe of that target and the recipes of any prerequisites of that target.

Specifically that scope **does not** extend to the prerequisite list itself.

So by way of example [this makefile](https://gist.github.com/deryni/897ff4584abc34fa8851#file-makefile):

```
SRCS := a.c b.c c.c

debug: SRCS+=d.c

all debug: $(SRCS)
        @echo ' $$^: $^'
        @echo ' $$(SRCS): $(SRCS)'
```

generates this output when run:

```
$ make
 $^: a.c b.c c.c
 $(SRCS): a.c b.c c.c
$ make debug
 $^: a.c b.c c.c
 $(SRCS): a.c b.c c.c d.c
```

You can read all about how make reads makefiles and about when variables are expanded in different parts of the makefile in the [How `make` Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) section of the manual.

As indicated this means that using `$(SRCS)` in the `debug` target's recipe would work here (as it has the correct value) but using the automatic variables does not but that's not exactly a good (or necessarily even possible) solution.

Another way to do this would be to make the assignment global but only do it when `debug` was the target being built. Something like this:

```
ifneq (,$(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    SRCS += src/test.cpp
endif
```

This won't let you run `make all debug` to build both (for example) but will work otherwise.

A few general comments on your makefile. You would do better than those `flex` and `bison` targets by teaching make how to run those commands on those pairs of input and output and just leaving it to do that.

Something like this:

```
src/tokens.cpp: src/65c816.l
    $(FLEX) -o $@ $^

src/math_tokens.cpp: src/math.l
    $(FLEX) -o $@ $^

src/parser.cpp: src/65c816.y
    $(BISON) -d -o $@ $^

src/math_parser.cpp: src/math.y
    $(BISON) -d -o $@ $^
```

and removing `flex` and `bison` from the `all` and `debug` prerequisites. No need to add anything else, make already knows it needs those `.cpp` files and now it knows how to generate them from sources so it will if it needs to.

Additionally `all` and `debug` don't want to depend on `$(SRCS)` and they don't need to. (They already do transitively through `$(EXE)` and `$(OBJS)`.

None of that solves the problem though. Unfortunately, there isn't a simple (good) solution to this problem. make doesn't support dynamic prerequisites this way.

The solution above about a conditional addition to `SRCS` is the closest solution I think you have here (and should work just fine as long as that happens before the `OBJ` assignment).

Actually, a slightly better solution might be to do something like this:

```
DEBUG_OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o) src/test.o

DEBUG_EXE := bin/yasa

debug: $(DEBUG_EXE)

$(DEBUG_EXE): $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: I've spend roughly 30 minutes trying to fix it based on your example, but it doesn't seem to work. My `all debug` target looks like the final `debug` in my post with your echo commands under it. If I remove `$(EXE)` it prints the correct files, but if I don't it gets to `$(EXE)` and says test.o doesn't exist. This makes me think even though the contents are being changed, they aren't being changed for the call that compiles everything and I still don't know why. I am about to just edit in a shortened version of my makefile so you can take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll probably end up doing the solution that doesn't allow both `all` and `debug` targets since I only build to one file for now. Also, thanks for mentioning the flex/bison thing. I had known that wasn't right for awhile but I'm not particularly good with makefiles. In fact, this makefile structure has been what I've used since 2012; I just copy it and put in the right files.

Comment: If the input and output file names matched on the flex/bison things you could combine them into a single pattern rule (one for flex, one for bison) and not need to duplicate the command and write out the file names this way.